# Problemas con datepicker de Bootstarp

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de usar el datepicker de manera dinámica. Hago una consulta a la base de datos y dependiendo de los registros existentes, "pinto" los calendarios. Cuando es un sólo registro no tengo problemas, pero, cuando son más de uno, me envía el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Esta es la forma en la que estoy definiendo las cajas:

```
<input id='txt_fechainicio' name='fecha_inicio[]' type='text' class='form-control datepicker' data-date-format='dd-mm-yyyy' required>
```

Además, de los calendarios que sí me abre, me marca de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguién tiene alguna sugerencia de lo que pudiera ser?

Comment: Puedes agregar el contenido de tu archivo JS donde haces el llamado de DatePicker para ver exactamento donde esta fallando.

Comment: Si pintas tu html desde php, concatena el id de cada registro al id del input que va ser de tipo datepiker. Ejem: id='txt_fechainicio-<?= $item->id; ?>' y desde tu js apuntas a cada elemento.

Comment: function calendario(){
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d',
    language: 'es'
   }).on('changeDate', function(e){
       $(this).datepicker('hide');
   });
  }
 //****

Comment: LuiscYm, en efecto, son varios casos los cuales debo de abordar, uno de ellos es el agregar el valor de la base de datos al input correspondiente, pero lo hago con js de la siguiente manera

<input id='txt_fechainicio' name='fecha_inicio[]' value='"+datos[0]["fecha_inicio"]+"' type='text' class='form-control datepicker' data-date-format='dd-mm-yyyy' required>